# Include package hierarchy with import

Tags: python, python-import

I'm new to Python, and especially new to structuring code in Python. I have a simple question, but I'm not sure how to phrase it. I'm looking for a command that imports a module while including its package hierarchy as part of its namespace/scope. Is this possible?. Here is a simple project to provide an example:

```
game (__init__.py)
    gameplay.py
    ui/
        window.py
        panel.py
        data.py
```

I believe I can import a module such as `ui/data.py` into `gameplay.py` using absolute syntax with something like:

```
import game.ui.data.py
```

But I think this requires digging into the hierarchy from the very beginning (the project name), regardless of where the module was imported or how the active module relates to the imported module. Example: `control = game.ui.data.controller`.

The only other type of importing I'm familiar with is relative importing:

```
from . ui import data.py
```

Which seems to dump off all of the module's parent packaging, importing the module like a child of the active module (`control = data.controller`).

So this is an (invalid) example of what I'm hoping to do in a couple situations:

```
from game import ui.data

control = ui.data.controller
```

After testing some things out, I figured out that I can write a package init file (`ui\__init__.py`) that imports all of its own files, then import that package name (`from . import ui`) directly into other files. The results are something similar to what I want, but I feel like this is probably a bad way to go about doing it.

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your second approach is good way.

an absolute approach is good way to keep everything intact, but i personally prefer doing a relative way (in case in future design change).

it's better to write a `__init__.py` inside each python package (python3+ import it without even a init file) , in this init frile you can write tge function you want to expose to outside python environment using `__all__` .

also instead of using `from game import ui.data` use `from game.ui import data` if data is unique here only  else do `from game import ui` then make a `uidata=ui.data(*args,**kwargs)`  or `from game.ui import data as ui_data`  (improvement suggestion by @smitelli)

for more project structuring read [PEP-8 guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Don't forget about `from some.pkg import foo as my_foo`.

Comment: Is there no direct way to import a single module while including its package hierarchy (minus the project module)? I'm also not entirely sure what is happening in the background during a package import - is there a down-side to importing a full package when you don't need all of the modules in the package?

Comment: in `ui/__init__.py` add `from data import controller` and `__all__ = ['controller']` then from outside you can import it as `from ui import controller` , maybe is this what you are asking about ?